# Write-up on own website or Medium: ask PR?

Tags: employer-relations

As part of my job, I researched a new framework, spent a couple days on it, in order to assess whether it would be a useful thing to work for.

I am considering writing a small write-up on my website, or on Medium, to share my thoughts about it.

Is this typical to involve my company's PR department? Do they typically have to OK it?

I understand this may be very company specific, but technical write-ups, post-mortems are a very common occurence in the tech world, so I think there is room for a general answer.

Comment: If you do it without seeking approval and someone decides that it violated something the company considered confidential, then you may face repercussions.  Otherwise, it's unlikely they will know.  Other companies encourage such publications and may even reward such things.  Generally it wouldn't hurt to ask if there are company policies about it.

Comment: PR?s no. Your boss?  yes.

Comment: Are you planning to use your company name? Are you planning to use your real name? Or a username that can be traced back to your company? What does your contract and employee manual say about this? If they say nothing, do not involve HR. Tell your manager and follow his/her suggestions/guidelines. Make your request over email. This way, if your manager ever leaves the company, you'll have a record of what was said. And if your manager ever changes, repeat the process again with your new manager. Your manager may forward your request to HR/PR, or to his own boss, but that's really his/her call.

Answer (score 4):

You probably should involve corporate PR if you're associating their name/brand to the article. You might also be required to talk to them if your contract or employee handbook so stipulates.

You may want to talk to your boss about it in either case.

As to publishing - put it on your own site as the canonical version, then publish it on Medium (there is a field to include the canonical URL to point back to your site).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to write it as a personal blog, leave all mention of your employer out of it.

If you really want to mention your employer, check with PR, and don't be surprised if the answer is "no". Companies (especially large ones) can be very fussy about who puts out anything in their name.

Answer (score 1):

Does your company legally own the framework you were researching? Do they hold any intellectual property rights?

If not, then I don't see why you'd need to involve them at all. The fact that you were researching the framework as part of your job should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably verify with your company a couple of things:

1. that you are not disclosing company intellectual property. This would be a big damage for your company and for you.
2. that you are cleared to publish anything work related in a way that can link you and what you write to your employer.

This depends on what is written in your contract and your company specific policies.
It might be, again depending on your specific situation, that somebody from the company will want to review your material before publication, to ensure it is clean.